# Create array for Data JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm starting with DataTables (https://datatables.net/)

And I'm trying to reload my table with json source.

From PHP code: I want to create an json array:

```
$fh = fopen("pv1_consultafolioTorre".".json", 'w');
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($query_result))
  {
     $a = array(
       array(
         'folio' => $row['folio'],
         'MATNR' => $row['MATNR'],
         'sucursalSolcitante' => $sucursalSolcitante,
         'sucursalResponsable' => $sucursalResponsable,
         'fechaSolicitud' => $row['fechaSolicitud'],
         'cantidadSolicitada' => $row['cantidadSolicitada'],
         'MATNR' => $row['MATNR'],
         'fechaConfirmacion' => $row['fechaConfirmacion'],
         'cantidadConfirmada' => $row['cantidadConfirmada'],
         'tiempoConfirmacion' => $result,
         'estatus' => 'Pendiente'
       ));

       $jsonencoded = json_encode($a, 128);
       print json_encode($a);
       fwrite($fh, $jsonencoded);
  }

  fclose($fh);
```

and I obtain this:

```
[
    {
        "folio": "99001091347",
        "MATNR": "033999900         ",
        "sucursalSolcitante": " CDG1 MATRIZ",
        "sucursalResponsable": " SC13 TIJUANA CENTRO",
        "fechaSolicitud": "2015-05-23 09:13",
        "cantidadSolicitada": 1,
        "fechaConfirmacion": "2015-05-23 09:14:47",
        "cantidadConfirmada": 1,
        "tiempoConfirmacion": 4,
        "estatus": "Aprobado"
    }
]
```

But I DataTables need the next structure:

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "99001091347",
            "033999900         ",
            " CDG1 MATRIZ",
            " SC13 TIJUANA CENTRO",
            "2015-05-23 09:13",
            "1",
            "2015-05-23 09:14:47",
            "1",
            "4",
            "Aprobado"
        ]
    ]
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
$output['data'] = [];

$fh = fopen("pv1_consultafolioTorre".".json", 'w');
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($query_result))
{
  $output['data'][] = array(
                    $row['folio'],
                    $row['MATNR'],
                    $sucursalSolcitante,
                    $sucursalResponsable,
                    $row['fechaSolicitud'],
                    $row['cantidadSolicitada'],
                    $row['MATNR'],
                    $row['fechaConfirmacion'],
                    $row['cantidadConfirmada'],
                    $result,
                    'Pendiente'
                );
}


print $jsonencoded = json_encode($output, 128);
fwrite($fh, $jsonencoded);
```

Comment: enough `$jsonencoded = json_encode(array('data' =>array($a)), 128);`

Comment: @splash58: Then you have the keys in the array. I do not know it that works with DataTables.

Comment: @Richard Reiber here is the output : {"data":[[{"folio":"99001091347"... Whatch there https://eval.in/369125

Comment: @splash58: In this case, if an object was returned must be in an array.

Comment: I see that output is that autor of the question wanted, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for you request Reza :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep the associative array for writing it to your .json-file and echo the data for DataTables, then you can fetch the [array values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) from your data array and create a new one for the JSON output:

```php
$json_data = array();

while($row = mssql_fetch_array($query_result))
{
    $data = array(
        'folio' => $row['folio'],
        'MATNR' => $row['MATNR'],
        'sucursalSolcitante' => $sucursalSolcitante,
        'sucursalResponsable' => $sucursalResponsable,
        'fechaSolicitud' => $row['fechaSolicitud'],
        'cantidadSolicitada' => $row['cantidadSolicitada'],
        'MATNR' => $row['MATNR'],
        'fechaConfirmacion' => $row['fechaConfirmacion'],
        'cantidadConfirmada' => $row['cantidadConfirmada'],
        'tiempoConfirmacion' => $result,
        'estatus' => 'Pendiente'
    );

    // write the array to a file if needed

    $json_data[] = array_values($data); // Transforming for DataTables
}

// Build the final DataTables array
$data_tables_array = array(
    'data' => $json_data
);

$jsonencoded = json_encode($data_tables_array);
echo $jsonencoded;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
$fh = fopen("pv1_consultafolioTorre".".json", 'w');
$arr = Array();
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($query_result))
  {
     array_push($arr, array(
         $row['folio'],
         $row['MATNR'],
         $sucursalSolcitante,
         $sucursalResponsable,
         $row['fechaSolicitud'],
         $row['cantidadSolicitada'],
         $row['MATNR'],
         $row['fechaConfirmacion'],
         $row['cantidadConfirmada'],
         $result,
         'Pendiente'
       ));
  }

  print $jsonencoded = json_encode(Array("data" => $arr), 128);
  fwrite($fh, $jsonencoded);

  fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. I have inserted $data = array('data' => $a); and changed $row[] in array as well. You will get desired output.

```
$fh = fopen("pv1_consultafolioTorre".".json", 'w');
        while($row = mssql_fetch_array($query_result))
          {
           $a = array(
                   array(
            $row['folio'],
            $row['MATNR'],
            $sucursalSolcitante,
            $sucursalResponsable,
            $row['fechaSolicitud'],
            $row['cantidadSolicitada'],
            $row['MATNR'],
            $row['fechaConfirmacion'],
            $row['cantidadConfirmada'],
            $result,
            'Pendiente'
           )
        );

    $data = array('data' => $a); // added by me.
    $jsonencoded = json_encode($data, 128);
    print json_encode($jsonencoded);
    fwrite($fh, $jsonencoded);

      }

      fclose($fh);
```